# How to prevent textarea from clearing the previous value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hello friends I want to prevent textarea from clearing the previous value
For example, I entered some data in the  and I clicked on Generate Code and I repeated entering the data and clicking again. I want the new data to appear below the previous data in the textarea
pls help me in my code if you can♥

```
  <div class="generator__questions" style="font-size: 18px; text-align: center;"><label for="youtubeVID">Company Name:</label><input id="youtubeVID" type="youtubeVID" class="youtubeVID" value name="youtubeVID" placeholder="enter company name" /></div>
<div class="generator__questions" style="font-size: 18px; text-align: center;"><label for="Companyloc">Location:</label><input id="Companyloc" type="Companyloc" class="Companyloc" value name="Companyloc" placeholder="enter company location" /></div>
 <div class="generator__questions" style="font-size: 18px; text-align: center;"><label for="headline">Website Url:</label><input id="headline" type="headline" class="headline" value name="headline" placeholder="enter website" /></div>
  <div class="generator__questions" style="font-size: 18px; text-align: center;"><label for="logo">Logo Url:</label><input id="logo" type="logo" class="logo" value name="logo" placeholder="enter logo" /></div>
  <div class="generator__questions" style="font-size: 18px; text-align: center;"><label for="blurb">Telephone:</label>
   <input id="blurb" placeholder="enter telephone" type="blurb" class="blurb" value name="blurb" /></div><div class="generator__questions" style="text-align: center;"><br /></div><div class="generator__questions" style="text-align: center;">
    <button class="generate-markup">Generate Code</button>
  </div></br>
    <center>
  <button id="btn">Clear input field</button></center>
  <div class="generator__markup">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Copy Your Page</h1>
    <pre><div style="text-align: center;" ></div><p id="p2"><code class="generator__markup-generated"></code></p><div style="text-align: center;"></div>
</pre>
<center>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p2')" class="copy-markup">Click To Copy</button></center></div></div>
<center>
<textarea id="con2"class="cont2" cols="42" rows="3" style="background: none 0% 0% repeat scroll rgb(0, 0, 0); color: white; height: 161px; line-height: 1.5em; width: 339px;" id="doubleClickBtn"></textarea>
  </center>

  <hr>

  <script type='text/javascript'>  
  //<![CDATA[
    const youtubeID = document.getElementById('youtubeVID');
    const headline = document.getElementById('headline');
    const blurb = document.getElementById('blurb');
    const Companyloc = document.getElementById('Companyloc');
    const logo = document.getElementById('logo');
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    
    btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    // clearing the input field
    youtubeID.value = " ";
          headline.value = " ";
          blurb.value = " ";
          Companyloc.value = " ";
          logo.value = " ";
})
    //]]>
 </script>
<script type='text/javascript'>  
  //<![CDATA[
const generate = document.querySelector('.generate-markup');

generate.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const youtubeID = document.querySelector('#youtubeVID').value;
    const headline = document.querySelector('#headline').value;
    const blurb = document.querySelector('#blurb').value;
    const Companyloc = document.querySelector('#Companyloc').value;
    const logo = document.querySelector('#logo').value;
  const cont2 = document.querySelector('.cont2')
    const markupContainer = document.querySelector('.generator__markup-generated');
    
    const markup = `
hello this is logo url :${logo}
${youtubeID}
${Companyloc}
    `;
    
    markupContainer.textContent = markup;
  cont2.textContent = markup;
});

function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
//]]>
 </script>
```

Comment: Use `+=` instead of `=` to append to the `textContent` instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try this in vue

```
    <template>
  <div>
      <h1>This is home page</h1>
      <textarea v-model="area" @focus="onFocus()"></textarea>
      <button @click="onClickGenerate(area)">Generate Code</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'IndexPage',
    data() {
        return {
            area: '',
            add: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onClickGenerate(data) {
            this.add = ''
            this.add += this.area
            this.area = ''
        },
        onFocus() {
            this.area += this.add
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The textarea used two way data bindings to state data "area", then whenever I press generate code, it will return the value of state data "area" to state data "add".
After it, then the textarea will be cleared and when the textarea focused, it will run a function which will add value from state data "add" to state data "area".